# Windows Mobile 6.5 Change the camera focus

Tags: c++, directshow, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a project to scan some QR-code or bar-code with camera on windows mobile. (phone x01t)
Programing in C++ and using DirectShow. 
Tired to change focus with IAMCameraControl interface, but return the error like "...request is not supported".
Are there any way else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most (if not all) Windows Mobile phones I've used so far used custom camera drivers, which means OEMs decide which functionalities to implement/support. IAMCameraControl is most likely not one of them.

However, you might want to look for OEM-specific SDKs. For instance, Samsung provides custom APIs enabling to change such parameters as camera focus or ISO. Maybe such APIs exist for your device.